# Is there a CRHF based on integer factorization problem or RSA assumption

Tags: rsa, collision-resistance

We know that in the black-box sense, we cannot use one-way functions to construct Collision Resistant Hash Functions.I feel that in my impression, I have never seen CRHF based on integer factorization problem or RSA assumption

Comment: One word: performance.

Comment: How about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_smooth_hash

Comment: Thank you so much @poncho

Comment: Now, I wonder if there is a hard problem that CRHF cannot be constructed on it

Comment: As a side note that wikipedia article is very funny --- when describing an asymptotic notion of security, it contains the line "This is considered a useless assumption for practice", and then describes a concrete security assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damgård constructed CRHFs from [claw-free permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_permutation), which can be based on integer factorisation (or even the discrete-log problem) [D]. That's the earliest one I am aware of (but someone feel free to correct me).

[D]: Damgård, [*Collision Free Hash Functions and Public Key Signature Schemes*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-39118-5_19), Eurocrypt'87

Comment: thanks, Now, I wonder if there is a hard problem that CRHF cannot be constructed on it.

Comment: Interesting. The concrete hardness assumptions I can think of also yield CRHFs. Will think about it.

Comment: Feel free to ask a question about that, but yes, there are many! For example, we don't know how to build CRHFs from one-way functions (for a generic assumption), or from the learning parity with noise assumption (for a concrete assumption - except in the extremely low-noise regime).

Comment: @ckamath, is there a CRHF based on graph isomorphism problem? I think maybe not

Comment: Right, but then we don't know any crypto from GI (and it might as well turn out to be easy).